# Local feature branch commit shows as a master commit on Network

Tags: git, github

Giving a go at the [Gitflow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) workflow and noticed something odd on Githubs Network tab.

On the remote I have 3 branches: master, develop and app (ignore this). On the local I have same branches, plus a feature branch: feature-1. At this point, my Network tab looked like this:

[image]

I performed the following git commands on the local after adding a single file to feature-1:

```
git checkout develop
git merge --no-ff feature-1
git push origin develop
```

And the resulting network looked like this:

[image]

Github's Network tab makes it look like there is a commit on master that is merged into develop, but that's not correct. Why doesn't Github show that a branch was created from develop, had commits, and merged back into develop? Something along the lines of:

```
master --------X
               |
develop        ------X            X
                     |            |
feature-1            -----X---X---X
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the tab, what you did on feature-1 is not being shown as part of master. Master is pointing at a revision behind and that's it. Then what you did on feature-1 is being charted at the same height as where master was coming, but it's not covered by master. Now, what you did in feature-1 is not visible on the remote repo. You moved your local develop branch and then pushed it into the same branch on the remote. Feature-1 was never pushed so it won't be displayed (actually, that remote has no idea of that branch. Consider that in git branches are not a part of the metadata of revisions... branches are just pointers to revisions... as such, they can be created, deleted, moved at will... in this case you have a local pointer that is never pushed to that remote). What can be seen from the chart is that you did some development on the side of develop... but I can think of more than one way of doing exactly that without using a separate branch.